# StackOverflow exception

Tags: exception, stack-overflow, dde

I am using DDE client to attach and listen stock market prices. That client has a callback method I implemented what to do when it receives price changes. The problem is that I get StackOverflowException (periodically and not at the same time interval). I found something about Thread.BeginCriticalRegion(), but I'm not sure if it would help. I have a few more hours until market opening when I can test it.
I would be more than greatful if someone could give me an idea how to override this exception.

Thanks in advance,
Aleksandar

`IList<SymbolObject> _symbols; //initialized when the app runs for the first time`

```
void _ddeClient_Advise(object sender, DdeAdviseEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!IsReady)
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Text))
        {
            _logMessages.LogMessagesAdd("advise dde symbol", string.Format("args.Text is empty or NULL for {0}", args.Item), true);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            string[] argsArray = args.Text.Replace("\0", "").Replace('\0'.ToString(), "").Split(' '); // sometimes happens here

            var list = _symbols.Where(s => s.DDESymbol == args.Item).ToList();
            if (list.Count == 0)
                return;

            decimal? val = null;
            try
            {
                var stringParts = StringUtils.CleanProphitXUrl(argsArray[0]).Split('.');
                argsArray = null;

                if (stringParts.Length >= 2)
                    val = decimal.Parse(stringParts[0] + "." + (stringParts[1].Length > 2 ? stringParts[1].Substring(0, 2) : stringParts[1]));
                else
                    val = decimal.Parse(stringParts[0]);

                stringParts = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logMessages.LogMessagesAdd("call Price Alerts application service", ex.Message, true);
                return;
            }

            foreach (var l in list)
            {
                if (_lastPrices[l.DDESymbol] == null)
                    continue;

                if (_lastPrices[l.DDESymbol].ToString() != val.ToString())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _quotePublishingService.PublishQuote(l.DDESymbolId, l.Symbol, args.Item, val, WebSyncPublisherUrl,
                            PublishingChannel); // a call to wcf service
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logMessages.LogMessagesAdd("call the service", ex.Message, true); // save to sql db
                        return;
                    }

                    _lastPrices[l.DDESymbol] = val.ToString();
                }
            }
            list = null;
            val = null;
        }
        catch
        {
        }            
    }

 public static string CleanProphitXUrl(string value) // StringUtils.CleanProphitXUrl snippet
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(value.Substring(0, value.LastIndexOf(".") + 1));

        try
        {
            value = value.Replace('\r'.ToString(), "").Replace('\t'.ToString(), "").Replace('\n'.ToString(), "");
            for (int i = sb.Length; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(value[i]))
                    sb.Append(value[i]);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `StackOverflowException` is caused by making to many method calls usually resulting from unintended recursion. Based on a cursory check of the code you posted I do not believe it is the culprit. The problem likely lies somewhere else.